# Jump is seq numbers from _changes

Tags: couchdb

There seems to be some form of inconsistency in the changes feed that I received from my couchdb and I am trying to seek your help to understand why this is happening. Please see below:

```
{"seq":2722,"id":"DeTelegraafOctober042015","changes":[{"rev":"2-49cb93be2bcc4d26077d1031ac42085d"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":2723,"id":"TelegraafJuly192015","changes":[{"rev":"2-494a7e8a0f675ebce9de154c1e388cb8"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":*2724*,"id":"TelegraafJuly262015","changes":[{"rev":"2-ce5e5f188852b98738dcb655fc4536f6"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":*2927*,"id":"manifest/vlucht","changes":[{"rev":"63-58b0db3c04d79175b13c718ba7ed98fe"}]},
{"seq":2949,"id":"AntilliaansDagbladOctober122015","changes":[{"rev":"3-be13d235a64f4bd860f9a06fcef57e0c"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":2978,"id":"AmigoeOctober142015","changes":[{"rev":"2-8883d294a1e6e4e32fb5390d2b1b3511"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":2979,"id":"ExpressOctober142015","changes":[{"rev":"2-bf0ceb629cf9dc35a94e5d6fc76de5fe"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":2998,"id":"AlgemeenDagbladOctober152015","changes":[{"rev":"2-ded3410bae81051cc91ffd2686f28857"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":2999,"id":"DeTelegraafOctober152015","changes":[{"rev":"2-5ec0979544e1d097941ca0943df37b6f"}],"deleted":true},
{"seq":3000,"id":"nl-NL/AntilliaansDagbladOctober152015","changes":[{"rev":"2-ad7e0561ab33b895179a4c25e0a8224c"}],"deleted":true}
```

Seq numbers of interest are marked is *. As you can see there is a jump in seq numbers of about 203 (difference between 2927 and 2724). And, there on its not as linear as 2722, 2723 and 2724.

Why is this happening ? Can this happen owing to compaction ? Any guidance/insight would be of great help. Thanks

Comment: Did you do a replication between 2724 and 2927? I'm not sure, but that might explain the jump. Another thing I notice is that the rev number on 2927 is much higher than the others, that might be a factor too.

Comment: @DominicBarnes I am checking if its a replication that caused this bump. Thanks for that input.